# In hyperledger fabric how to use user's key-pair for encryption and decription?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

By using Hyperledger fabric 1.4 SDK I have created one user, a set of public and private key is generated for that user. Now I want to use this key pair for encrypting and decrypting the data.

I aware hyperledger uses elliptic curve cryptography for signing the data, but I don't know in background how they are signing the data. I tried several method in nodejs but didn't get success.

following are my keys generated while registering the user

```
public key:
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEBWLnhsBfNE+hF1uDuDb/Z87KAPvF
6RCQLtgZIxdU4x5qcTdEWQPOfF2fUSrecmHAfgMW1cMiun0B9KAaMY7dFg==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

private key:
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgmQndljBNeyPyvEDM
lPtXtibQ8yYwK05RfLhkl/sCJ5WhRANCAAQFYueGwF80T6EXW4O4Nv9nzsoA+8Xp
EJAu2BkjF1TjHmpxN0RZA858XZ9RKt5yYcB+AxbVwyK6fQH0oBoxjt0W
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

by using following method I'm able to sign by using public key but for verifying I'm getting **Unknown point format error**

```
var EC = require("elliptic").ec;
var ec = new EC("secp256k1");
var mySign = ec.sign(msg, public_key);
var res = ec.verify(private_key, msg, mySign)
```

Can any one suggest the suitable method for signing the data by using hyperledger key pair.

Comment: could you give me public_key, private_key? using console.log. I am curious if you match the type correctly.

Comment: these are my keys:
private key :  <Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 42 45 47 49 4e 20 50 52 49 56 41 54 45 20 4b 45 59 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0d 0a 4d 49 47 48 41 67 45 41 4d 42 4d 47 42 79 71 47 53 4d 34 39 41 ... >

public key :  <Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 42 45 47 49 4e 20 50 55 42 4c 49 43 20 4b 45 59 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0d 0a 4d 46 6b 77 45 77 59 48 4b 6f 5a 49 7a 6a 30 43 41 51 59 49 4b 6f ... >

Comment: When referring to the ec library, the input parameter seems to be the hex string, not the buffer type. I am curious to see if the type of the function input parameter is properly matched. See link [elliptic](https://github.com/indutny/elliptic/tree/e71b2d9359c5fe9437fbf46f1f05096de447de57)

Comment: Yes in ec library the key pair are in hex string and I tried to convert it as a hex string by using .toString('hex') method and got the same response

Comment: I also tried [this example](https://gist.github.com/nakov/1dcbe26988e18f7a4d013b65d8803ffc) by using **keyFromPrivate()** and **getPublic()** method i'm getting the hex key and signing and verify is working fine but in this case I'm ignoring the existing keys, I have to use existing keys for the operation.